# ¿Como cambiar en Vuejs 3 Options Api el estado v-show en listado de registros laravel, sabiendo el id de laravel?

Tags: vue3

Tengo un listado de productos en laravel (no se usa v-for) sino @foreach, el cual itero obteniendo una tabla en html. En cada producto que se muestra hay un botón que contiene un id y la propiedad v-show=true, que muestra el botón. Tambien tengo un método ShowHide que recibe el id de laravel y lo pasa al js de vue.

```
 @foreach

<button type="button" :id="b1{{$reg->id}}" v-show="true"  @click="ShowHide({{$reg->id}})">ON</button>

endforeach
```

Si conozco el id del elemento, como le indico en el js que a ese elemento en particular cambie el estado de v-show=true por v-show=false?

Vengo de AngularJS y ahí podía hacerlo fácilmente con:

```
$scope['b1'+$scope.id] = false;
```

pero en vue todo lo similar que intente no lo toma. Mi nivel de frustración con este tema ya esta en defcon 3. Gracias.